# How can I configure a MI424WR wireless router to provide specified DNS servers to DHCP clients?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I have a MI424WR wireless router. How can I configure it to provide specified DNS servers to DHCP clients so that they use my internal DNS server, instead of the routers built-in DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the router via the web interface
2. Click on "My Network"
3. Click on "Network Connections"
4. Click on "Broadband Connection (Ethernet/Coax)"
5. Click on "Settings"
6. Enter in values for "Primary DNS Server" and "Secondary DNS Server"
7. Click "Apply"

New DHCP hosts will now be provided with the specified DNS servers.